# Is it possible to set multiple websites in different S3 buckets, under the same domain but different subfolders with lambda @edge?

Tags: vue.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, vue-router

I have two Single Page Applications in Vue.js (And the vue-router setting is history mode) . I want to host them in different S3 buckets but in same CloudFront distribution. And I want to set URL like this:

1. `custom-domain.com/site1/`
2. `custom-domain.com/site2/`

Is it possible to set multiple websites in different S3 bucket, under the same domain but different subfolders with lambda @edge?

Comment: I don't think you need Lambda for this at all, just configure multiple origins in your CloudFront distribution.

Comment: @MarkB I tried it. It worked well when I enter the default route. But I found the some problems when I changed page route. The CloudFront response 403 Forbidden.

Comment: @TylerSmith, Mark B's suggestion should work for the scenario you are describing. Could you give a bit more detail of the circumstances your attempt failed and the path expression you were using?